# How to associate a list of items with a single row?

Tags: sql, database-design

I've seen some similar questions on here, but none had the answer that I need.

I need a way of associating multiple items with a single entry in a many-to-one relationship. The only catch is that those items have to be associated with other entries as well. Imagine an entry as recipe of sorts and the items as the parts/ingredients. Those parts could be required for multiple recipes.

The most ideal solution would be that each recipe entry somehow contains an array of item IDs, but such a thing is sadly not possible with SQL databases. The only real solution that I could come up with is a table for recipes that just stores recipe ID, name, description, etc. and a table that relates recipe ID to item ID. Yet this solution seems impractical since I'll end up with a table with a bunch of repeating IDs in both columns.

To clarify, this is what I mean:

```
recipeID | itemID
101      | 1001
101      | 1002
101      | 1012
102      | 1001
102      | 1031
103      | 1030
103      | 1031
103      | 1032
```

As you can see, it gets messy and repetitive really fast. Is there a better way to handle this?

Also, would it be better to use a NoSQL document-oriented database in this scenario? That was another idea I had.

Comment: The many-to-many scenario you have is really a pretty acceptable outcome.  It allows for the unknown number of "items" for each "recipe", allows for reuse of "items", and is actually very useful when processing the info automatically - better than some kind of embedded list or array.  Can you share what is the downside for your work?

Comment: Example http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/sales_receipts_generic/index.htm

Comment: @MikeM it just doesn't feel natural to me. As you might have guessed, I'm fairly new to databases, so to me it seems more natural to use something like an array, as I would if I was writing a Recipe class in C++ or something. Having data in separate tables doesn't seem logical to me, but I guess it's the best way when it comes to managing data.

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.  This might be the common case of getting used to "set-based thinking".  When you operate on this data, your programs shouldn't be reading all of it randomly.  For example, when displaying the items for a single recipe, your query should be pulling all Items for one key Recipe with a single, direct query on that key value.   It won't be an issue, programmatically, to have that outcome - in fact, it will be easier.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is exactly how you should handle it. It is normalized. It is called a junction table: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table

Comment: So I should end up with three tables (excluding the other data I need to store)? One for recipes, another for items and a third to connect the two?

Comment: That's exactly the idea.